# Can I install files directly onto to PS3 HDD?

Tags: ps3, hard-drive

Can I install files directly onto the PS3 HDD?

The way I plan on doing so is..

```
1.Take out the PS3 HDD

2.Connect the HDD to my laptop to the HDD with a USB converter

3.Put the files into whatever folder they go in (Don't know yet)

4.Save and Put the HDD back into the PS3
```

(Does anybody know what folder I will put games and eboots in?)

Answer (score 5):

Nope, you can't.

Every single PS3 hard drive is encrypted to it's own, personal, PS3.  No two keys are the same, and that's not even taking into account the file structure required.  You won't even be able to *read* the hard drive, let alone throw information onto it.

Incidentally, what you're trying to do here is piracy.  But even with legitimate data, what you're intending to do won't work at all.